# Cannot create lightbox

Tags: html, css

I am using the following div:-

```html
<div style="position:absolute:z-index:150;top: 0; left: 0;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;background-color:black;opacity:0.4;"></div>
```

But its displaying nothing.

Comment: Please never use inline style and provide a codepen if possbile

Comment: @LiXinyang Using the snippet editor HERE is better than a codepen in most cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your inline CSS. You've written `position:absolute:z-index:150;` while it should be `position:absolute; z-index:150;`. So change that colon to a semicolon.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 150;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```